# What did the native inhabitants of Gojoseon call themselves?

Tags: korea

I have found on Wikipedia that the inhabitants of Gojoseon (2333 BC - 108 BC) were called [Dong-i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AGojoseon), or Eastern Bowmen, by the Chinese, but I cannot find what the official name/ethnicity of the people that lived there was.  If possible, could you include sources so I may go back and do more research?

This is not as necessary, but I would appreciate it if anybody could tell me what the inhabitants of the Three Kingdoms of Korea (Baekje, Silla, and Goguryeo) were called too.

Comment: Called by whom?

Comment: @T.E.D. Themselves

Comment: Most people call themselves some variant of "people". Its everyone else but "us" who's weird and needs a special name.

Comment: @T.E.D. Then Is there a generalized name that we as society use for them today?

Comment: @seppemane Gojoseon literally meant Ancient Korea. This was not a single state, nor society, nor probably people. The language of ancient Korea is likewise not singular nor known with any certainty, and might be effectively unattested. From the perspective of today, you may as well call them Ancient Koreans or proto-Koreans. Finally, in Chinese records Dong-i historically refers to the natives of Shandong peninsula, not Korea.